# React Higher Order Components - export wrapped component or wrap it in parent?

Tags: comparative-review, react.js, jsx

I've been learning about about how to use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context), and how to make a [higher order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to provide context values through props.

So, I've created my HOC to pass down the props, and it looks like this, in a file called `ConsumerWrapper.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import {ThemeContext} from "../context/fakeContext";
import hoistNonReactStatic from 'hoist-non-react-statics';

export function ConsumerWrapper(WrappedComponent) {
    const EndComponent = props => {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Consumer>
                {({theme, toggleTheme}) => (
                    <WrappedComponent {...props} theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme}/>
                )}
            </ThemeContext.Consumer>
        )
    };
    EndComponent.displayName = `ConsumerWrapper(${getDisplayName(WrappedComponent)})`;
    hoistNonReactStatic(EndComponent, WrappedComponent);
    return EndComponent;
}

function getDisplayName(WrappedComponent) {
    return WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name || 'Component';
}
```

Then I made a component which was made to be Wrapped, in `WC.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import {ConsumerWrapper} from "./ConsumerWrapper";

function WC(props) {
    const {theme, toggleTheme} = props;
    return (
        <div style={{color: theme.foreground, background:theme.background }}>
            <p>hello world from WC</p>
            <p>{props.secondaryMessage}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ConsumerWrapper(WC);
```

As you can see, in that file I export the component already pre-wrapped. That way, in my other files, I can just use it like so:

```
import WC from "./components/WC";
...
return (<WC secondaryMessage="second message here"/>)
...
```

---

HOWEVER, it occurs to me that there's an alternative: that instead of exporting the wrapped component in WC, I wrap it in the files that use it. So my `WC.jsx` would look like this:

```
import React from "react";

export default function WC(props) {
    const {theme, toggleTheme} = props;
    return (
        <div style={{color: theme.foreground, background:theme.background }}>
            <p>hello world from WC</p>
            <p>{props.secondaryMessage}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And then when I want to use it, I have to wrap it first:

```
import WC from "./components/WC";
import {ConsumerWrapper} from "./ConsumerWrapper";
const WrappedWC = ConsumerWrapper(WC);

...
return (<WrappedWC secondaryMessage="second message here"/>)
...
```

In general, is the second one preferred to the first? The second one allows me, in the future, to provide alternative (maybe even non-context related) props for `theme` and `toggleTheme`, so in the second one, the component seems less "bound to the implementation" so to speak, less coupled.

Was hoping I could get some advice on this. Thanks.